# Attendance marking in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i've tried match/vlookup and other simple formulas which i can find over the net but to no avail. Appreciate if i can get any advice or help from here.

Problem:

I have an ordered attendance list, i want to be able to type in a random name in a fixed empty cell. It will run through the column with the names and mark a "absent" or "present" in the adjacent cell next to the name if a match is found.

Is this even possible with basic excel?

P.S: New to excel, pardon me if I've broken any rules here.
I'm using excel 07 and I do not have background in VBA.

Edited title.

Comment: This would require more than basic Excel skills. If it can be done, it would have to be with VBA. Somehow Excel will need to know which choice, `absent` or `present`, if a match is found.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(MyColumnWithTheNames,MyName)>0,"Present","Absent")
```

as in

```
=if(countif(A1:A5,C1)>0,"Present","Absent")
```

QUestion would be in a better spot on superuser though.

Comment: Agreed. I’ve voted for it to be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: This doesn't work. My names are in columns A1:A5. I type in a random name, for example, in cell C1. It will run through A1:A5 and if it finds a match, it will mark a "present" or "absent" in the adjacent cell of the matched item (B1:B5).

Comment: What is superuser may i know?

Comment: so you can only have one present at a time?